# How to "paint" a grid of JLabels with mouseDragged event?

Tags: java, swing, conways-game-of-life

I'm currently trying to reproduce the Game of Life. The implementation is done, but I want to add a painting mode. If this mode is activated the user should be able to turn every dead cell the mouse is currently on into a living one by dragging their mouse over them (dragging, not clicking, just like drawing something in Paint). Each JLabel-object on the grid represents one cell. The state of the cell is determined by its color. I got the paint-mode to work, but it only works when I start dragging the mouse on the background of the JPanel, if I start doing it on a JLabel, it does nothing. Should I perhaps use something else than a JPanel? Here is my code so far (CellLabel inherits from JLabel):

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.util.Random;

public class CellLabelGrid extends JPanel {
  private final CellGrid cellGrid;
  private final CellLabel[][] cellLabels;
  private Color aliveColor;
  private Color deadColor;

  public CellLabelGrid(Game game, int rows, int cols) {
    initializeColors();
    this.cellGrid = new CellGrid(rows, cols);
    this.cellLabels = new CellLabel[rows][cols];
    this.setLayout(new GridLayout(rows, cols));
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
        CellLabel cellLabel = new CellLabel(game, cellGrid.getCellAtIndex(i, j), aliveColor, deadColor);
        cellLabels[i][j] = cellLabel;
        this.add(cellLabel);
      }
    }
    this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(rows * 50, cols * 50));

    MouseMotionListener mouseMotionListener = new MouseMotionListener() {
      @Override
      public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        int mouseX = e.getX();
        int mouseY = e.getY();
        if (game.getGameMode().equals(Mode.PAINT)) {

          for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
              if (mouseX >= cellLabels[i][j].getX() && mouseX <= cellLabels[i][j].getX() + cellLabels[i][j].getWidth() && mouseY >= cellLabels[i][j].getY() && mouseY <= cellLabels[i][j].getY() + cellLabels[i][j].getHeight()) {
                if (cellLabels[i][j].getBackground().equals(deadColor)) {
                  cellLabels[i][j].setBackground(aliveColor);
                  cellLabels[i][j].getCell().setState(CellState.ALIVE);
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }

      @Override
      public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
      }
    };
    this.addMouseMotionListener(mouseMotionListener);
    this.setVisible(true);
  }

  public CellGrid getCellGrid() {
    return cellGrid;
  }

  public CellLabel[][] getCellLabels() {
    return cellLabels;
  }

  private void initializeColors() {

    Random rand = new Random();

    float r = rand.nextFloat();
    float g = rand.nextFloat();
    float b = rand.nextFloat();

    aliveColor = new Color(r, g, b);

    float r2 = rand.nextFloat();
    float g2 = rand.nextFloat();
    float b2 = rand.nextFloat();

    deadColor = new Color(r2, g2, b2);
  }

  public Color getAliveColor() {
    return aliveColor;
  }

  public Color getDeadColor() {
    return deadColor;
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to also make a MouseListener. Both MousLeistener and MouseMotionListener are in the MouseAdapter class, that you can choose to override methods of.

Comment: @JustanotherJavaprogrammer even if I don't need any methods from MouseListener?

Comment: When you start dragging the mouse from a `CellLabel`, the source of the `MouseEvent` is `CellLabel` and not `CellLabelGrid`. Hence your `mouseDragged` method is not called. If you want me to offer you a solution, you need to post a [mcve]. Alternatively, post the code for classes `CellLabel` and `CellGrid`

Comment: Also post code for `Game`, `CellState` and `Mode`. You are asking for help in debugging your code. I can't do that without reproducing your problem and I can't reproduce your problem based on the code in your question.

Comment: @Abra I just solved my problem while making a minimal reproducible example. I had another game mode which would change the state of each cell by simply clicking on a CellLabel, that's why it didn't react while in painting mode. The MouseListener from CellLabel was overriding the MouseMotionListener from CellLabelGrid.